# Converting string to the name of a class member c#

Tags: c#

Suppose i have the following class and i have an object (let it be called "obj1") created of it with some values. -

```
public class parameters
{
   public string TYPE { get; set; }
   public string label { get; set; }
   public string prev { get; set; }
}
parameters obj1 = new parameters();
obj1.TYPE = "asdf";
```

suppose i have a string denoting one of the member names

```
string member_name = "TYPE";
```

how can i access the value of whatever name is there in the string of the object obj1 based ?

```
var val = obj1.member_name ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it using reflection:

```
var propertyInfo = typeof(parameters).GetProperty(member_name);
var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj1) as string;
```